# Is there a way to replace and trim values in individual fields using the dbf to csv python library dbf by ethanfurman?

Tags: python, csv, dbf

I am using the python library, [dbf](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/), by Ethan Furman to convert a number of dbf files to csv.  It works extremely well for that.  I would like to further edit some of the fields during the conversion process but am unsure how to do it.  Specifically, I would like to replace string fields that contain only 1 or more blanks with empty strings, (eg. "   " replace with "") and date fields that contain "00000000" with empty strings "".  I would very much appreciate it if someone could describe how to edit the fields and write out the updated records during the conversion process.  Obviously, I could write a simple secondary script to edit the csv files output during conversion but I would like to do it all in one step if possible.  Here is the code I am using to convert the files:

```
import csv
import dbf
import os
import sys

folder=sys.argv[1]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.DBF'):
            db=dbf.Table(filename, ignore_memos=True)
            db.open()
            csv_fn = filename[:-4]+ ".csv"
            dbf.export(db, filename=csv_fn, format='csv', header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when using a dbf table the data types returned are simple -- i.e. `int`, `str`, `bool`, `datetime.datetime`, etc.  But you can make your own data types and have those used instead by specifying them in the `default_data_types` parameter:

```
db = dbf.Table(
        filename,
        ignore_memos=True,
        default_data_types={
            'C': my_white_space_stripping_data_type,
            'D': my_empty_date_str_data_type,
            },
        )
```

Fortunately, `dbf` comes with four enhanced data types already:

- `Char` -- automatically strips trailing whitespace, and ignores trailing whitespace for comparisons
- `Logical` -- supports `True`, `False`, and `None` (`None` is returned when the field value is not true or false -- I've seen `?`, `' '`, and other weird garbage)
- `Date` -- supports an empty date, such as `00000000`, and displays them as `''`
- `DateTime` -- supports an empty date/time, and displays them as `''`

Typically, if you're using one of the enhanced data types you probably want them all, so instead of the dictionary you can just pass a string:

```
db = dbf.Table(
        filename,
        ignore_memos=True,
        default_data_types='enhanced',
        )
```

Now, when a csv file is exported, trailing white-space is dropped, and empty date fields become `''`.

Keep in mind that empty logical fields will become `'?'` instead of `''`, so you may want the longer form of specifying a `dict` to `default_data_types` and only overriding `C` and `D`.

Comment: I am sure it is something minor but I am now receiving the following error after adding the "default_data_types" segment:  
`File "/data/clients/hcp-nv/load/raw/scripts/convert_dbf_to_csv_using_dbf_all_matching_files.py", line 11, in <module>
    db=dbf.Table(filename, ignore_memos=True, default_data_types='enhanced_data_types')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbf/__init__.py", line 5529, in __init__
    for field, types in default_data_types.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`. 
suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: @always_learning: Sorry, it was still early -- the string should be 'enhanced'. Answer fixed.